# Compile/run nothing happpend

Tags: vba, excel

hi guys I finish this code but nothing happen when I run it, this is my first code with vba.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    N = Range("A").End(xlUp).Select
    M = Range("B").End(xlUp).Select
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    For i = 1 To N

        If Cells(i, "A").Value = "2015 Xor 2011" Then
            Cells(j, "B").Value = "blue"

        ElseIf Cells(i, "A").Value = "2001 Xor 2003" Then
            Cells(j, "B").Value = "green"

        ElseIf Cells(i, "A").Value = "2014 Xor 2006" Then
            Cells(j, "B").Value = "red"
            j = j + 1

        End If
    Next
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Did you run through it step by step with the debugger ? What is the value of N ? Also, j is never defined.

Comment: Yes did try, but excel stops every time I do so. N value is supposed to be the length of my dynamic array 1D (column) and j has been defined as Interger (second line)

Comment: I'm sorry I meant j has never been initialized. You need to use the debugger and see what N actually is because you might find that your code is wrong (which it is if it's not working as expected).

Comment: As @AlexandreP.Levasseur said j = 0 the first time through.  There is no cell at B0, before your loop j must be set to something greater than 0.

Comment: you haven't defined N and M. but from your code that would be the range variable. But you have used it as an integer in the Loop? Have you checked for that?

Comment: This is the same code as before and I had corrected it for you,http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33542724/next-without-for-vba-compile-error/33543142?noredirect=1#comment54871272_33543142

Answer (score 0):

You need to edit how the `N` and `M` integers are set. It looks like you want to get the last row in a range, so you'll switch `.select` with `.row`, and instead of using `Range("A")` (which doesn't work), choose the very last cell in columns A and B, then use the equivalent of <kbd>CTRL + UP</kbd> to get the last row.

```
    N = Cells(rows.count,1).End(xlUp).Row
    M = Cells(rows.count,2).End(xlUp).Row
```

You hadn't set `N` or `M` to anything.  Using `.Select` just selects the cells, and doesn't necessarily apply a numerical value to that variable.  The above should work, but if not, let me know!